# Restrict Web Service Calling after entering into previous fragment where service is called already

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webservice

How to restrict multiple web service calls in fragments in the following scenario shown below[image]

I have learned about Fragment life Cycle but don't know exactly where to use life cycle methods for my problem. Please help me on this.thanks in advance